# beeque jobs not getting emitted after the scheduled time

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, redis

I am using beequeue version (1.4.0) with redis version (2.8.0), when i am scheduling a job in beequeue with the epochtime of 1 min after the current time i.e epochtime = date.now()+1 min, sometimes it gets emitted and most of the time it does not. what could be the reason for this?

below is the code for setting the epochTime (schedule Time)

```
    const currentTimeUTC = DateUtil.getCurrentDate();
    console.log('currentTimeUTC- :', currentTimeUTC);
    const startTimeEpoch = DateUtil.addDelayToTime(currentTimeUTC);
    static addDelayToTime(utcTimeString: string): number {
        const utcDate = new Date(utcTimeString);
       
        utcDate.setMinutes(utcDate.getMinutes() + 1);
       
        return utcDate.getTime();
    }
    static getCurrentDate(): string {
        const date = new Date().toISOString(); 
        return date;
    }
    static convertToStandardUTC(timeString: string): string {
        
        const date = new Date(timeString);
        
        const year = date.getUTCFullYear();
        const month = String(date.getUTCMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
        const day = String(date.getUTCDate()).padStart(2, '0');
        const hour = String(date.getUTCHours()).padStart(2, '0');
        const minute = String(date.getUTCMinutes()).padStart(2, '0');
        const second = String(date.getUTCSeconds()).padStart(2, '0');
       
        const utcTimeString = `${year}-${month}-${day}T${hour}:${minute}:${second}.000Z`;
        return utcTimeString;
    }
```

I tried googling but couldn't find a single blog/ article with this issue.
i just want that it should work fine making sure all the jobs get emitted according to their scheduled Epochtime. `